# Count non-transparent pixels in a canvas

Tags: beginner, coffeescript

I need to count non-transparent pixels in a canvas. I am pretty sure there is a nice and elegant syntax for doing this. Note that the data returned by `getImageData` is not a regular array and cannot be sliced, for example, or it does not have a `reduce` method.

```
data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data
count = 0
i = 0
for x in data
  if (i + 1) % 4 == 0 && x > 0
    count++
  i++
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?!

```
data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data
count = 0
count++ for x, i in data when (i+1) % 4 is 0 and x > 0
```